# Expressing $f(f(x))$ when $f(x)$ is a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, functions

This is a question from MIT OpenCourseWare about calculus. I cannot find any explanation online since I have no idea what the keywords are.

The question states that:

$f(t)=\begin{cases}
2t & \textrm{if }0\leq t\leq3\\
12-2t & \textrm{if  }3<t\leq6
\end{cases}$

It asks to find the 4-parts formula of $f(f(t))$

I do not understand why the domain of f(f(x)) would be divided into 4 parts, which are $0≤t≤1.5$ , $1.5<t≤3$, $3<t≤4.5$ and $4.5<t≤6$

**UPDATE:** 
Intuitively, I think it will only have two parts, which are:

$f(t)=\begin{cases}
2(2t) = 4t & \textrm{if }0\leq t\leq3\\
12-2(12-2t)= 4t-12 & \textrm{if  }3<t\leq6
\end{cases}$

I don't understand the $2(12-2t)$ as well as the $12-2(2t)$ part.
$f(t)= 2t$ $\textrm{if }0\leq t\leq3\\$, so why do we have to consider the $3< t\leq6\\$ part when outputting $f(f(t))$ when $0\leq t\leq3\\$

Comment: Think about what the image of the function is. Draw the function and then have a look.

Comment: Which are the two parts you are thinking of?

Comment: I have updated my question, thanks for the response.

Comment: What is $f(f(2))$?

Answer (score 0):

If $t\in\left[0,\frac32\right]$, then $f\bigl(f(t)\bigr)=f(2t)=4t$. If $t\in\left[\frac32,3\right]$, then$$f\bigl(f(t)\bigr)=f(2t)=12-2\times(2t)=12-4t.$$And so on. So, yes, you need four intervals.

Comment: But I still do not understand why it behaves in such a way. I have updated my question, thanks for the response.

Comment: If $t\in\left[\frac32,3\right]$, then $f(t)=2t\in[3,6]$. Therefore, $f\bigl(f(t)\bigr)=12-2\times(2t)=12-4t$. So, why do you claim that $f\bigl(f(t)\bigr)=4t$ instead?